# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

Tags: vb.net, wcf, rest

When I call the restful service with the following code, I am getting the error

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a receive.

Code:

```
    Const url As String = "http://localhost:8003/Tracker/Tracker.svc/GetTrackerDetails"

        ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 500
        ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = True
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
        ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = True
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = ServicePointManager.DefaultPersistentConnectionLimit

        req = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        req.Method = "POST"
        req.ContentType = "application/xml; charset=utf-8"
        req.Timeout = 300000
        req.KeepAlive = False
        req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", url)


        Dim xmlDoc = New XmlDocument With {.XmlResolver = Nothing}

        xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("Request.xml"))
        Dim sXml As String = xmlDoc.InnerXml
        req.ContentLength = sXml.Length
        Dim sw = New StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream())
        sw.Write(sXml)
        sw.Close()

        res = DirectCast(req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Dim responseStream As Stream = res.GetResponseStream()
        Dim streamReader = New StreamReader(responseStream)

        'Read the response into an xml document
        Dim soapResonseXmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
        soapResonseXmlDocument.LoadXml(streamReader.ReadToEnd())


        TextBox1.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(soapResonseXmlDocument.InnerXml)
        soapResonseXmlDocument.LoadXml(TextBox1.Text)
```

I am facing this error for the past few days. What is wrong with my calling code. Please help me out.

Comment: Two clarifications: 1) Does the service work if you invoke it via a browser ? 2) I see you perform a POST request, if answer to my first question is 'yes' switch to GET

Comment: When I invoke the service through browser, I get "Method Not Allowed" I need to work with POST method only. I am passing XML as request. Is it not possible with POST? I am calling it through client code. But not browser

Comment: Previously it was working with post. I have changed the request xml by adding child nodes and sub child nodes to it. From then i am getting this error

Comment: `I have changed the request xml` should have been the headline of the question in the first place. Error means your service doesn't "understand" the new request.

Comment: This is the changed request xml . <TrackingDetailsReq xmlns="http://xx.com/abc/ns"> <TrackingNumbers> <TrackingNumber>A10001</TrackingNumber> <TrackingNumber>A10002</TrackingNumber> </TrackingNumbers> </TrackingDetailsReq>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install some logging on the connection, in this case I would guess the request or response is to big for the client or server.

Comment: What are the logging tools available for rest and where do we need to install it either client or server?

Comment: I am getting only single message in Service Trace Viewer log i.e., AppDomain Unloading

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be occurred from service when it's failed to parse your request XML or getting unknown exception error while it is processing the request.